# Problem with `tlmgr` in WSL2

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, update, texlive2022

### Infos

The installation was done on a new computer .

- Platform : Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- texlive2022.iso mirror : https://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2022.iso

### Problem

I installed texlive2022 in WSL with an iso file.
When I type `sudo tlmgr update --list` , the terminal gives this :

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

### My Installation steps

current folder : `~`

1. execute `sudo apt install fontconfig` and `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
2. create folder ( `sudo mkdir /mnt/texlive` ) then mount the iso file ( `sudo mount ./texlive2022.iso /mnt/texlive` )
3. execute `sudo /mnt/texlive/install-tl`
4. enter `I` ( the default installation )
5. unmount the iso file ( `sudo umount /mnt/texlive` ) and delete folder ( `sudo rm -r /mnt/texlive` )
6. edit `~/.bashrc` then append the following contents to the file :

   ```
   # Add TeX Live to the PATH, MANPATH, INFOPATH
   export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
   export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
   export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
   ```

   then exit , execute `source ~/.bashrc` and `tex -v` , and everything is alright .
7. Now dealing with the font : `sudo cp /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf`
   and execute `sudo fc-cache -fsv` to refresh the cash.
8. upgrade texlive packages : `sudo visudo` and append `:/usr/local/texlive/2022` to the end of the `secure_path`
9. choose the default mirror : `sudo tlmgr option repository ctan`

Then comes the problem. Do you have any suggestions? Thx.

Comment: you are running the debian system texlive (which is updated using apt) not the one from tug (updated using tlmgr) If you have installed the  tug one check your PATH. `type tex` should show `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/...` not `/usr/bin`

Comment: Okay ... so what should I do ? delete all of them or ...

Comment: if you installed from TUG just set your PATH in your .bash_profile or whatever startup file you use, see  step 6 of https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Okay I just figured it out : I should **prepend** the location , not **append** .

Answer (score 0):

PS : The installation was done on a new computer .

The problem is on step 8 : I **append** `/usr/local/texlive/2022` to the end of the `secure_path` .

Actually we should **prepend** it , i.e. `secure_path="/usr/local/texlive/2022:....."`

Comment: Welcome. // If this is a solution (or work-around at least), please express it a bit clearer. If it's not, please move your // P.S. to your question. Reason: We try to have 1 problem statement (question), followed by many solutins (answers). Therefore we  try to avoid what's normal in other groups: chit-chat.

Comment: Its done . Thanks for your suggestion .